# Does material time derivative physically make sense?

Tags: reference-frames, time, differentiation, flow, continuum-mechanics

[image]

where $u$ is the velocity field.

So one term of the material time derivative tells us how much the field is changing with its motion along particle, and another when it's fixed in position and changing with time alone.

My confusion is that in real life we can actually fix position and let time pass and observe what's happening at that specific fixed position but we can't actually freeze time and just observe the change in field quantity when its moving alone the particle since the time is already changing when moving with the particle.

So how does the given partition in material time derivative work in this sense? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "motion along particle" and "moving alone the particle"?

Comment: @Hoody I mean due to changes of particle position

Comment: "Freezing time" and finding Dq/dt doesn't make sense since the particle moves as a function of time. I assume you are confused what setting $ \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} = 0$ represents. This doesn't mean to freeze time, it means to say that the function itself does not change with respect to time.

Answer (score 2):

I believe all the 3 terms in the equation physically make sense. For convinience, let's talk about a river flow and let $q$ be a temperature.

- $\dfrac{\mathrm Dq}{\mathrm dt}$ tells you how the temperature changes around a specific "molecule" of water which you follow in space and time. That's what you call "move along the particle". You can approximately measure this if you throw a wireless thermometer into a river and let it flow away.
- $\dfrac{\partial q}{\partial t}$ tells you how the temperature changes with time if you simply stare into a single point in a river, your eyes not following the water flow. You can measure this when you mantle a thermometer to a stone in a river so that it is not taken away by the water.
- $\nabla q$ tells you how temperature changes in space at some particular fixed time. There is no principal issue mantling several adjacent thermometers to several nearby stones in the water and measuring the temperature profile at one time.